# Silverlight serialisation/deserialisation problem

Tags: silverlight, datacontractserializer, isolatedstorage

I'm looking for a way to persist Silverlight objects to a user's PC, then re-hydrate them so the user can finish editing them.

Serialising with `DataContractSerializer` and persisting to `IsolatedStorageFile` works fine. However, deserialising causes a problem.  Here's the code that causes the failure:

```
private string _FirstNames = string.Empty;
public string FirstNames
{
    get { return _FirstNames; }
    set
    {
        new PersonNameValidator().Validate(value);  //<-- BOOM 8(
        Set(ref _FirstNames, value, () => this.FirstNames);
    }
}
```

The deserialiser calls the property setter, which in turn throws an exception and aborts the deserialisation.

I've tried explicitly applying `DataContract`/`DataMember`/`IgnoreDataMember` attributes, but then it doesn't play nicely with private fields:

> System.Security.SecurityException
>   occurred   Message="The data contract
>   type
>   'Trident.Model.Journey.JourneyApplication'
>   cannot be serialized because the
>   member '_TravellerSavingsAmount' is
>   not public. Making the member public
>   will fix this error. Alternatively,
>   you can make it internal, and use the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute
>   on your assembly in order to enable
>   serialization of internal members -
>   see documentation for more details. Be
>   aware that doing so has certain
>   security implications."

How can I bypass the property setters during deserialisation?

I'd like to keep my classes focused on the domain, and not too polluted with infrastructure concerns.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

- serialize a property that is used only for serialization thereby bypassing any validation
- serialize a parent class and use a derived class for validation

Comment: Thanks Joel.  I considered the first point, but dislike the idea of adding extra public properties/fields just to support serialisation.

As for using derived classes: this could get cumbersome as my object graphs increase in complexity. I don't want to write a custom routine to handle every object graph I create.